# ASP.NET Core - dotnet bundle watch stops detecting changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm running 'dotnet bundle watch' on an ASP.NET Core application to automatically run the bundler when I save changes to my .js files. It processes as expected at first, but after the first or second save in Visual Studio 2015 the bundler just hangs at "Watching..." and doesn't react to any subsequent changes made to the input files.

It will work pretty reliably that first time after restarting Visual Studio, and it sometimes seems to be willing to detect a change if I wait 5-10 minutes and try again. The inconsistency of it makes me wonder if it's just a bug. Running 'dotnet bundle' works fine every time.

Here's my bundleconfig.json:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/file.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "renameLocals": false
    },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? I've blown the better half of the day trying to get to the bottom of this with no luck.